# Average Minimum Distance between Curve and Circle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, geometric-probability

I aim to formalize the average minimum distance between any point on a circle with a radius $r$ and an infinitely long curve.

I know the location of the curve and circle, but there is no formula for the curve as its application is geographic data, e.g. borders, rivers, etc.

I want to formalize the average distance. So far, my approach, [as visualized here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6UbT.png), is as follows:

- define $d$ as the minimum distance between point A on the circle and the curve. B is the closest point on the curve.
- define $\phi$ as a random variable uniformly distributed in $[0,2]$

My results so far:

1. As far as I understand, there is no way to explicitly formalize $d$, i.e., I would have to compute it.
2. I can however define $d$ as a function of $\phi$. The average minimum distance between any point on the circle and the curve is then given by:
   $\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}{d(\phi) d\phi}$.
3. This can be computationally approximated by $\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}{d(\frac{i}{N}\phi)}$

I feel like there should be a better way to formalize the relationship, but I don't know how.

Comment: $r$ doesn't need to be an argument of function $d$, $r$ can be considered as parameter. Then $\langle d \rangle = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} d(\phi)\, d\phi$.

Comment: true, I changed it above.

Comment: As long as the circle doesn't intersect the line, $\frac12(d(\phi) + d(\phi + \pi ))$ is distance of circle's center to the line...

Comment: Line in maths usually means a straight line. Better to say curve.

Comment: I think [Hausdorff distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance#) should be interesting for you.

Comment: If you analyze how Hausdorff distance is computed, you will see that it is close to what you are doing.

Comment: Strange not to have any reaction from you ...

Comment: thank you very much for the comment and sorry for the late reply. I haven't had the time to check Hausdorff distance, but will get back to you once I know whether it is useful for my setup!